# Adding pdf page for each record in dataframe. Python PDF reporting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyfpdf

I trying to iterate through pandas table and add PDF page for each row using FPDF library. The script only adds the very last record in the table and generates one page. I'm trying to figure out how to add a page for each record

```
import pandas as pd
from fpdf import FPDF
filename = 'alley.csv'
df= pd.read_csv(filename)

class PdfReport:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename


    def generate(self, first_name,last_name, address_lane,city,zip_code, amount):
        pdf = FPDF(orientation='P', unit='pt', format='A4')
        pdf.add_page([])

        pdf.set_font(family="Times", size=24, style='B')
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=80, txt="Report Header", border=1, align="C", ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt="Year: 2021 ", border=1,ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt=first_name, border=1, ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt=last_name, border=1, ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt=address_lane, border=1, ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt=city, border=1, ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt=str(zip_code), border=1, ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt=str(amount), border=1, ln=1)
        pdf.output(self.filename)

for ind in df.index:
    pdf_report= PdfReport(filename="Report1.pdf")
    pdf_report.generate(df['first_name'][ind], df['last_name'][ind], df['address_lane'][ind], df['city'][ind], df['zip_code'][ind],df['amount'][ind])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with a few edits made to your code.

```
import pandas as pd
from fpdf import FPDF
filename = './alley.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

class PdfReport(FPDF):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        FPDF.__init__(self) #initializes parent class
        self.filename = filename

    def generate(self, first_name,last_name, address_lane,city,zip_code, amount):
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.set_font(family="Times", size=24, style='B')
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=80, txt="Report Header", border=1, align="C", ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt="Year: 2021 ", border=1,ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt=first_name, border=1, ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt=last_name, border=1, ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt=address_lane, border=1, ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt=city, border=1, ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt=str(zip_code), border=1, ln=1)
        pdf.cell(w=0, h=40, txt=str(amount), border=1, ln=1)

pdf = PdfReport(filename)
pdf.alias_nb_pages()

for ind in df.index:
    pdf.generate(df['first_name'][ind], df['last_name'][ind], df['address_lane'][ind], df['city'][ind], df['zip_code'][ind],df['amount'][ind])

pdf.output('PDF_TEST.pdf','F')
```